# Build a minimal no_std-binary on all platforms

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-no-std

I need to *test* a build-dependency in a `#[no_std]` environment. The environment created by Cargo for build-dependencies is primarily that of the host, not the target, yet there are subtle differences if the to-be-compiled crate is `#[no_std]`. What I can do as part of integration testing is to create a minimal dummy-crate (which depends on the to-be-tested build-dependency) on disk, and spawn a new Cargo process to build that crate, using Cargo's exit status as the test's fixture. The question is how to build a `#[no_std]` binary with Cargo without requiring the current installation of `rustc` to include foreign targets (e.g. `arm...`, `thumb...`) or implicitly depend on the platform the tests are currently getting executed from.

The most basic setup to build (not run!) such a minimal `#[no_std]` crate would be

```ini
[package]
name = "nostd"
version = "0.1"
build = true

[build-dependencies]
to_be_tested = ...

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort" # we don't need no panic-handling
```

... and a `main.rs` like the following; it needs to be `main.rs` because libraries don't get to decide if the final crate links to `std` or not.

```rust
#![no_main]
#![no_std]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_panic: &PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
    // won't ever get executed anyway
    loop {}
}
```

However, this fails to build with

```
rror: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: [...]
  = note: ld: warning: no platform load command found in '[...]/symbols.o', assuming: macOS
          ld: Undefined symbols:
            _main, referenced from:
                <initial-undefines>
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The crux of a missing `main`-stub is that - afaics - it's signature depends on the current target, and I would like to build said dummy-crate on whatever the build-dependency is currently being tested on. How to do that? Do I need to include platform-specific `main`s for the major platforms and `#[cfg]` those? Or can the problem be avoided altogether - the crate does not actually need to run, it only needs to build!

Comment: *'libraries don't get to decide if the final crate links to std or not.'* - that's not entirely true - if a library isn't `no_std`, then it decides that the final crate must link to std. If you have `#![no_std]` in the code of your library, then it doesn't **matter** if the final binary links to std or not - it should work in both cases. What exactly are you trying to test here? Why is it not enought to simply build the library?

Comment: @Finomnis, yes, I was overly specific on that point. To your second point: cargo/rustc does not behave the same if a `#[no_std]` library is build vs. if a `#[no_std]` binary is built. AFAICS, even though a no_std-library can't link against stdlib, it is build as if it could; this seems to be a quirk, which is why I need the test.

Comment: What's this observation based upon? *'build as if it could'* - of course. It doesn't need the stdlib, but it doesn't prevent an executable from linking against it; why should it. That doesn't change the behavior of the library, though.

Comment: what is your host machine? and your target triplet? also what is the command that you used which yielded that error? If you don't want to run the program and just want to use it as dependency then write the code in lib.rs instead of main.rs

Answer (score 1):

AFAICS, you'll need a `no-std` `target` compatible with your hardware. I guess `x86_64-unknown-none` should work in most cases.

Then, you'll need to add an appropriate entry point in `main.rs`:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn main() -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

`cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-none` will then execute `build.rs` and compile successfully.